# Block (temporarily) new programs from starting?

Tags: windows, block

Occasionally when doing processor heavy tasks on Windows, I don't want other applications from starting (such as scheduled backup, virus scans, etc.).

Instead of having to disable each of these processes beforehand, is there a way I can blanket block any new processes from starting (temporarily).

UAC blocks processes until user authentication, and what I am asking for is not too different, so I thought there might be a way.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy way to prevent applications from starting. It can be done with [Software Protection Policies](https://patrickwbarnes.com/blog/blog/2009/09/06/defending-windows-with-application-whitelisting/), but they aren't the easiest thing to setup (and you need to be super careful to do it correctly).

If you want your process to preempt others, the best solution is probably to just have it run at a higher [CPU](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686219.aspx) priority. You can also set the memory and IO priorities using undocumented internal APIs if needed. Keep in mind that processes created from Scheduled Tasks run at lower priorities by default.